# CQRS vs. SQL vs. NoSQL for Clojure mobile app

Tags: sql, web, clojure, nosql, cqrs

The context is a mobile app that involves a lot of social networking.

I am not sure whether to use MongoDB or Postgresql for my database system. I have recently learned of CQRS and it seems an appealing solution to the problem. However, I can't find any implementations of it, nor much in the way of libraries that support communication between the two different database models.

Would a combination of Postgresql and Mongo be a potent solution to the problem?

Comment: CQRS vs (No)SQL is like apples vs fruit baskets

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure without spending a lot more time thinking about what you are going to do, so in the not-SQL category I'll just throw my vote out there for [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) because it's fun and many [people smarter than](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-Design-of-Datomic) I see it as a [good fit](http://pedestal.io/) for large scale Clojure programs.

Comment: Datomic looks like a cure-all if not for a few things things that bother me; it's not open-source, and if it's cloud based does that mean I can't have my own datomic database on my hard-drive?

Comment: Also does Datomic provide a solution to command-query separation?

Comment: Datomic has multiple storage backends, several of which can be self hosted. CQS to me seems more of a concern with OO, and less applicable to Datomic because of its immutability principles.